# CsvHelper Ignore case for header names

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have some class

```
public class Import
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

In csv file header names can be in lowercase.
How I can ignore case while reading file?

```
    var reader = new StreamReader(@"///");
    var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
           
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Import>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are using the http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ you can provide some configuration when constructing the CsvReader or configuring it after construction.

```
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(yourString))
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(stringReader))
    {
        // Ignore header case.
        csvReader.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch =  (string header, int index) => header.ToLower();
        return csvReader.GetRecords<Import>().ToList();
    }
```

There is more documentation in the PrepareHeaderForMatch section at https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/Configuration/

For more granularity there are also class mapping instructions for which can be found under here:
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration

Hope that helps.

Comment: Going the `PrepareForMatch ToLower()` route - wouldn't that require the C# class you're binding to to have its properties all lower case? I.e. still requiring that the casing of the input and your model match? Otherwise again... they'll have different cases. Requiring matching case is far from "case insensitive"

Comment: Random old CsvHelper code shows `csvReader.Configuration.IsHeaderCaseSensitive = true;` but this Configuration property doesn't look to be a part of the library now? Looks like the silver bullet was removed.

Comment: @mmcrae I thought the same thing at first but according to the documentation, "The header field and the member name are both ran through this function."

Comment: @DonCheadle the ToLower() is run over the headers from the file as well as the properties of the class, so in effect a case-insensitive comparison is done.

Comment: Hi all, this solution is no longer supported as the configuration API has changed. For me, @Ambrose Leung's change worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/67167414/9301751

Answer (score 27):

In the current version of CsvHelper, you have to configure it like this:

```cs
var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    PrepareHeaderForMatch
    = args => args.Header.ToLower()
};
using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputFile))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: In order to avoid inconsistency with current culture, use `ToLowerInvariant`.

Answer (score 1):

A blog post from Mak (2022-09-26) has three different ways to configure CsvHelper.

> When your CSV header names don’t match your property names exactly,
> CsvHelper will throw an exception. For example, if your header name is
> “title” and your property name is “Title”, it’ll throw an exception
> like: HeaderValidationException: Header with name ‘Title'[0] was not
> found.
>
> If you don’t want to (or can’t) change the names to match, then you
> can configure CsvHelper to map headers to properties with different
> names. You have three options:
>
> - Use the *[Name] attribute* on properties that need it.
> - Use CsvConfiguration.*PrepareHeaderForMatch* when there’s a pattern to the
>   naming differences (such as a casing difference).
> - Use a [ClassMap](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/) to explicitly declare how all properties should be mapped.

[C# – Configuring CsvHelper when the header names are different from the properties](https://makolyte.com/csharp-configuring-csvhelper-when-the-header-names-are-different-from-the-properties/)