# Reading CSV file when header is present with lower (or) upper case

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am using CSVHelper libraries of version 2.7.1.
I want to read CSV values when the header is present in lowercase.
I am reading CSV below

```
sr = new StreamReader(fs);
using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(sr))
{
csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = hasHeaderRecord;
csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = false;
csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreReadingExceptions = true;
csvReader.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
csvReader.Configuration.TrimFields = true;
csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap();

FileRecords = csvReader.GetRecords().ToList();
}
```

how to read CSV values with the lower (or) upper case?
Can we do without upgrading to the latest CSVHelper packages?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower

Comment: I don't believe the CSVHelper library dictates the case of a CSV header it is reading. Have you got some code that cares about the case of a string? Shouldn't `RegisterClassMap` have a generic type parameter?

Comment: Yeah, make sure the value of hasHeaderRecord is true for this particular file

Comment: Set `csvReader.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToLower()` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67167414/3744182) by Ambrose Leung to [CsvHelper Ignore case for header names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49521193/3744182).  In fact this looks like a duplicate, agree?

Comment: However, you may want to use `ToLowerInvariant()` instead of `ToLower()` if your CSV file is not localized.

Comment: @dbc I am using older version of CSVHelper class. So I am not getting PrepareHeaderForMatch

Comment: @user768853 - Can you upgrade to a later version?  [2.7.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/2.7.1) was released on 8/30/2014; the current version, [30.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/30.0.1), is substantially different and better.

Answer (score 0):

[Probably,](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#reading-a-csv-file)

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToLower(),
};
```

Comment: I am using older version of CSVHelper class. So I am not getting PrepareHeaderForMatch

Comment: @user768853, use the newer version?

Answer (score 0):

CsvHelper version [2.7.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/2.7.1) had configuration options:

- [`IsHeaderCaseSensitive`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/2.7.1/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L109) - indicates whether column name matching is case sensitive.
- [`IgnoreHeaderWhiteSpace`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/2.7.1/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L120) - indicates whether column name matching ignores whitespace.
- [`TrimHeaders`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/2.7.1/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L134) - indicates whether headers should be trimmed.

Thus you should be able to set

```
csvReader.Configuration.IsHeaderCaseSensitive = true;
```

Do note that, in CsvHelper 3.0, all of these options were replaced with [`Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/3.0.0/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/Configuration.cs#L147):

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Prepares the header field for matching against a member name.
> /// The header field and the member name are both ran through this function.
> /// You should do things like trimming, removing whitespace, removing underscores,
> /// and making casing changes to ignore case.
> /// </summary>
> public virtual Func<string, string> PrepareHeaderForMatch { get; set; } = header => header;
> ```

Even if you can't upgrade to the [latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/) (currently [30.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/30.0.1)) you might consider at least upgrading to version [3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/3.0.0).  See: *[CsvHelper Ignore case for header names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49521193/3744182)*.